# Corner Circle Menu CSS and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

I am trying to create a corner circle menu as shown in the image below:

[image: Corner Circle Menu Sample]

This is what I have tried and achieved:

```js
$(".menu").click(function(){
    $(".menu-items").fadeToggle();
});
```

```css
html,body{
 color:#000;
}

.menu{
 position:fixed;
 left:-100px;
 top:-100px;
 z-index:9999 !important;
 width:200px;
 height:200px;
 border-radius:50%;
 background-color:#3F51B5;
}

.menu .menu-btn{
 position:absolute;
 bottom:50px;
 right:50px;
}

.menu-items{
 position:fixed;
 top:-100;
 left:-100;
 z-index:9990 !important;
 width:250px;
 height:250px;
 background:#2979FF;
 border-radius:50%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>Corner Circle Menu</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="menu">
  <div class="menu-btn">Menu</div>
 </div>
 <div class="menu-items">
  <div class="menu-item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="menu-item">Item 2</div>
  <div class="menu-item">Item 3</div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have been trying to achieve this from 2 days but was unable to find any relevant codes or ideas or logic. Please could anyone explain/guide me the mathematics and css behind this design?

Comment: Search for "CSS pie slice" and learn how to do that, then just use whole circles and overlay them in the top left corner -> https://jsfiddle.net/d7vvntmk/

Comment: Yep that's something similar to what I was searching for. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to creating the menu items is to put them in a circular div and set the circular div to overflow hidden, rotate each one of them and skew them.
Check out this tutorial: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/08/09/building-a-circular-navigation-with-css-transforms/